# QSelection model invalidates on update

Tags: c++, qt

I am using inbuilt QSelection model in qt for a QTableview.The model that is supplied to this view is continuously refreshed each second based on input received from a stream.So if i select a cell in the view, every time i receive a new input and i refresh my model then the selection model gets invalidated and now nothing is selected.I want my selectionmodel to be persistent and unless the selection is removed by the user i dont want it to be invalidated. How can i achieve this???

```
ui->testTable->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->testTable->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
```

these are the attributes that are set.Do i have to set anything else too ??
And does it have an impact if i use a proxymodel??

Comment: How are you notifying the system that your model data are being updated? Are you using the dataChanged() signal or the modelReset() signal?

Comment: for using just selection model i should throw a signal ???

Comment: At the time an update occurs, can you set the QItemSelectionModel::NoUpdate flag and then restore it?

Comment: restore what ?? sry i am just starting with qt

Comment: @user2454413, when you update your data inside your data model class, you're supposed to emit some kind of a signal so that other objects (like the QSelectionModel, or QTableView) know that they must update their own internal data structures.

Comment: What data model are you using?